# Extend Custom Attribute Value Limit from VARCHAR 255 to 500

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, attributes, varchar

OK had a look round and cannot seem to find an exact solution to my problem.

I have a custom attribute that stores a link, on some cases this link can be up to 500 characters long.

When I show show the link on my website the link is only part there.

Where do I change the default 255 limit as I do not want to have any additional scripts running to ensure they are saved correctly in `catalog_product_entity_varchar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have been over thinking it, I was under the impression that Magento sent the limit over when adding the value but this is not the case as I have changed the column value and it has stayed at `VARCHAR(500)` when adding new entries.

To change it to `VARCHAR(500)` I used the following in MyPHPAdmin:

```
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_varchar`
  CHANGE COLUMN `value` `value` VARCHAR(500);
```